# EC2 instance creation and polling until state is 'running' using boto library

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, fabric

I want to create a new spot instance using boto library and run some commands on it using fabric. I'm using the below code

```
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
status = instance.update()
tries = 40
i=0
while status == 'pending':
  log.info("Status of instance: [ " + job_instance_id + " ] is pending")
  time.sleep(10)
  status = instance.update()
  i=i+1
  if i > tries:
    break
log.info("Status of instance [ " + job_instance_id + " ] is " + status)
if status == 'running':
  log.info("Adding tag")
  instance.add_tag("Name", "test_tag")
  public_dns_name = instance.public_dns_name
  log.info("Host Name : " + public_dns_name)
  init_instance(public_dns_name)
```

In init_instance I'm running some commands using fabric. These commands fail sometimes with "Unable to connect to host" error. Sometimes it works fine without any issues. Can you please let me know why does it fail sometimes? How can I handle this? I already keep polling untill the state of the instance changes to 'running' and run the commands via ssh only after the instance state moves to 'running'

Comment: The canonical way to do this is to use UserData or cloudinit. The machine can then "pull" configuration, or at least it can notify a process.

Comment: Yeah, just because the instance state is "running" it doesn't necessarily mean that all services on the instance are fully operational.  The sshd process is probably still initializing.  If you want to poll that, you can use something like paramiko to programmatically poll for SSH access.  Or, as @tedder42 suggests, you can add something to cloudinit.

Comment: @tedder42 What is coludinit ? How can I use it to ensure sshd is up and running before initiating a connection?